# Copy all figures in a column and paste it to row with ID value 1 smaller

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want a SQL query to copy a column, and paste it to ID 1 smaller. (see sample below) Due to system limitation, I can only do it in a SQL query.
Is SQL good at doing such calculation?

Sample input

```
[id] [old]
1    11
2    13
3    14
4    15
6    17
7    18
10   20
```

Sample output

```
[id] [old] [new]
0    null  11     (new row of id 0 created, for placing 11)
1    11    13
2    13    14
3    14    15
4    15    null   
5    null  17     (new row of id 5 created, for placing 17)
6    17    18
7    18    null
9    null  20
10   20    null
```

Comment: Try a self join. BTW, what's the expected result if you add the row (10,20) to the input data?

Comment: I have added row (10,20) input and output to the question. I am wondering if I need to insert the new rows by an insert query.

Comment: what's your DBMS? Oracle,MySQL?

Comment: microsoft sql server

Comment: seems an outer join is unavoidable! But I am told to avoid outer join whenever possible, when I was in school. Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create missing records, then update against the following one.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#AvailableIDs') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #AvailableIDs

CREATE TABLE #AvailableIDs (ID INT, OldID INT)

INSERT INTO #AvailableIDs (
    ID,
    OldID)
VALUES
    (1, 11),
    (2, 13),
    (3, 14),
    (4, 15),
    (6, 17),
    (7, 18),
    (10, 20)


INSERT INTO #AvailableIDs (
    ID)
SELECT
    ID = ID - 1
FROM
    #AvailableIDs AS A
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #AvailableIDs AS X WHERE X.ID = A.ID - 1)


UPDATE A SET
    OldID = X.OldID
FROM
    #AvailableIDs AS A
    LEFT JOIN #AvailableIDs AS X ON A.ID = X.ID - 1


SELECT A.ID, UpdatedID = A.OldID FROM #AvailableIDs AS A ORDER BY 1
```

Result:

```
ID  UpdatedID
0   11
1   13
2   14
3   15
4   NULL
5   17
6   18
7   NULL
9   20
10  NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I like it because it avoided a full outer join nicely.

Answer (score -1):

You can solve this problem with a pretty basic query and no secondary tables (or updates):

```
with ids as (
      select id
      from t
      union -- on purpose to remove duplicates
      select id - 1
      from t
     )
select ids.id, t.old, lead(t.old) over (order by ids.id)
from ids left join
     t
     on t.id = ids.id;
```

Here is a [rextester](http://rextester.com/VMNS80351) showing the results.

Here is another version with no `join`:

```
with t as (
      select *
      from (values (1, 11), (2, 13), (3, 14), (4, 15), (6, 17), (7, 18), (10, 20)
           ) v(id, old)
     ),
     ids as (
      select id, old, null as new
      from t
      union all
      select id - 1, null as old, old as new
      from t
     )
select ids.id, min(old) as old, min(new) as new
from ids 
group by ids.id;
```

Comment: And why would a demonstrably correct solution be downvoted?